Showing letter of recommendation to student
When I was applying for jobs one of my letter writers sent me the letter he wrote for me after I submitted his applications. It was a very nice and touching letter, and I think he had meant for it to be a token of encouragement I could remember him by.
Now I am in a position of writing a letter for one of my students. Would showing them the letter after they have submitted their applications be considered ethical?

I show my students drafts. See my answer to a related question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/202781/top-3-in-reference-letter-when-applying-to-yale/202786#202786

It is ethical, it's just not a good idea. When you have something genuinely positive to say about a candidate, you might as well say it to their face by showing them the letter. The problem is that that sets an example you might not want to follow through when you have to write a letter for someone you don't think is brilliant -- you don't want to show a lukewarm letter to that person. As a consequence, it's probably a good strategy to just never show people letters.
(As humans, we should also always strive to tell people good things when we think positively about them. But that's a separate issue.)

Note, however, that in some parts of the world a curious student can request to see the letter and is legally entitled to do so. Although in practice few will.

When you can only write a lukewarm letter, you should probably discuss that with the student before writing the letter, anyway

@ScottSeidman You get the idea. Not every letter we write can be equally good. Some necessarily need to be better than others.

I show letters to my students/former students once they have the offer, and specifically if they are going into a position that is in academia/national lab where they will also be asked to write letters for people. It is difficult to know what a good letter is like if you have never seen one. This is part of the training process.

There is absolutely nothing unethical about showing a student a letter which you have written for them.  The anonymous nature of letters of recommendation is there to protect the writer from being pressured by the person for whom the letter is being written, and to ensure that the writer feels free to be open and honest in their letter—someone who knows that their letter will be read may not be so candid.  So it might be ethical concerns if writers were required to disclose their letters, but there is no problem with writers choosing to do so.
In addition, contrary to Wolfgang Bangerth, I do not see any others causes for concern if you decide to show a letter to someone for whom you have written a letter.  That said, I would recommend that you establish an all-or-nothing policy:  either you are willing to show anyone the letter you write for them, or you are not.  You don't need to be overly public about this, but you should at least have some internal consistency.  This removes the concern about showing great letters to great students, and not showing lukewarm letters to others.
For myself, I would never agree to write a letter for someone if I was not comfortable showing them that letter.  When a student asks me for a letter, I have a frank discussion with them about the kind of letter I will be able to write—if I can only say lukewarm things, then I will explain this to the student and give them the option to find another letter writer.  If the student is okay with a lukewarm letter (or, indeed, insistent that I write them a letter), I will write that for them, and happily give them a copy of the letter.
